# ServerAgent file not running during Jmeter CPU utilization

Tags: asp.net, jmeter, cpu-usage, jmeter-plugins

When I am trying to use Jmeter for load testing my .Net based application, I have to run Startagent.bat file on server where project files are kept. But, somehow this file is not running.

Is it mandatory to have JRE installed on your server as well ?

How to test CPU Utilization for .Net based application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside `startAgent.bat`, you will see:

```
@echo off
java -jar %0\..\CMDRunner.jar --tool PerfMonAgent %*
```

So, yes, to run startAgent on any server, you will need a Java Runtime installed on that server.

Comment: Thanks, I got the point.
But we don't have permission to install JRE on server.
I am trying to figure out ways to test CPU utilization for .Net web application which is a CRM.
Can you suggest something?

Comment: Sure. As I am new to this, wasn't much aware about protocols to be followed. I'll raise a new question.

Comment: What OS does your sever run? You should be able to run perfmon on a Windows server and mpstat on linux server to get detailed CPU stats.

Comment: We use Windows. Perfmon is running but due to JRE not being installed at Server, its not giving the output.
I am looking for a tool to test CPU utilization on a .Net based architecture.

Comment: I'm not talking about the jmeter plugin. see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749154.aspx) and [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/283/performance-monitor/)